# Javascript this reference in prototype function - removing indexes from array like object

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have the following code (which is either misunderstood by me or syntactically wrong)

```
Object.prototype.sliceElementsWithinByTagName = function(t) {
for(var i=0,len=this.length;i<len;++i){
    if(arguments[1]){ 
        if(this[i].tagName == t){ 
            delete this[i] ; 
        } 
    }else{ 
        if(this[i].tagName != t){ 
            delete this[i] ; 
        }
    }
}
```

}

Essentially i want to have an available method to remove all references in an object that are not of a certain tag type (or vice versa).

Im running the function like `object.sliceElementsWithinByTagName('LI')` but the indexes supposedly delete in the prototype function are not being deleted in object.

Comment: If you just pass one argument (`'LI'`), the code as written will delete entries whose "tagName" property does not match that argument. Is that what you expect? Also putting such a function on the Object prototype doesn't make a lot of sense; it makes the untested assumption that the object has a "length" property.

Comment: really im just messing around because im unfamiliar with prototype, but yea i wanted to delete all non-'LI' entries.